# How to style d3.js selection as individual elements?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use D3.js and Leaflet and I want to style every circle with different color. I have function who checks one variable value and depending on that variable it returns fill color for that circle. It shows only one circle after this code and not all array(points):

```
 map._initPathRoot();

var svg = d3.select("#map").select("svg"),
    g = svg.append("g");
 var feature = g.selectAll("circle")
            .data(points)
            .enter().append('svg')
            .each(function (d, i) {        
                   d3.select(this).selectAll('circle')
                        .data([d])
                        .enter()
                        .append('circle')
                        .attr('r', 10)
                        .attr('stroke', 'white')
                        .attr('stroke-width', 1)
                        .attr('opacity', 0.8)
                        .style('fill', getFeatureColor(d)) //returns "red"  
            });
map.on("viewreset", update);
        update();

        function update() {
            feature.attr("transform",
                function (d) {
                    if (d !== undefined) {
                        return "translate(" +
                            map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).x + "," +
                            map.latLngToLayerPoint(d.LatLng).y + ")";
                    }
                }
            )

        }
function getFeatureColor(d) {
        if(d.count>20) {
           return "red";
        }
        else {return "blue"}
}
```

Comment: what is `getFeatureColor(d)`?

Comment: function which returns for example "red";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, there is no need for extra SVG elements and iterating twice over the data. You can create the circles directly using points array as shown below.

Hope this helps.

```
var feature = g.selectAll("circle")
  .data(points)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', 10)
  .attr('stroke', 'white')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1)
  .attr('opacity', 0.8)
  .style('fill', function(d){ return getFeatureColor(d) });
```